# How do I create a horizontal list with bullet separator in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to create a horizontal layout list of items for a promotional poster. It is much like a music festival line-up poster. After each list item I need a custom bullet or separator. After the last item on a line the separator needs to be skipped. This is true also for each item that stands alone on a line.

I know I could do this quite easily using each list-item as an individual object, but the list is ever changing and I'd just like to know if its possible.

This is an example of what Im asking that I mocked up in Photoshop.

Thanks!

[image: Mock Up in Photoshop]

Answer (score 2):

Text, space, bullet, space - repeat.

Set the text justification to centered. And at times, you may want to use - text, space, space, bullet, space, space, repeat.

If you want to use a custom bullet image, size the custom image appropriately then copy it and then it would be -- Text, space, paste, space, repeat.

You could also use tables in Indesign to get slightly better spacing. In this case you would use - Text, tab, bullet, tab, repeat. Then select the line of text and bullets and choose `Table > Convert Text to Table`. You can then set the table width to match the column width you want and distribute columns evenly. At times, this assists in extending the spacing between the text and bullets for a more fluid look than if you were to insert a bunch of spaces before and after bullets.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ALT key combination to insert a bullet character into the text. The ALT key combination for a bullet in windows is 0149.

- With numlock enabled
- **Hold** down the **ALT** key
- Type 0149 on the **keypad**
- Release the Alt key

This will not work using the regular number keys as far as I am aware, it has to be on the keypad on the right hand side of the keyboard.

There are loads more symbols you can do, check this link out:
http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough, but I've been struggling inserting bullets without a carriage return. The "Bullets and Numbering" menu which seems to only be able to create bullets by line (vs horizontally).

For those that, like me, may need some extra help making this happen, Ctrl+Alt+X inserts a NON-breaking space (to keep characters together on the same line), and you can use Ctrl+8 to insert bullets in-line. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

•   ALT+7   Circle bullet
◘   ALT+8   Reverse bullet
○   ALT+9   Empty bullet
◙   ALT+10  Reverse bullet

Comment: I'm sure these are wrong too...